# Entity Framework and MySQL - not returning number of affected rows

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I've got a stored procedure that is called via a DBContext like so:

```
using (var transScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TimeSpan(0)))
{
   using (var db = new IceCreamEntities(connectionString, null, null))
   {
      db.CallMyProc(dateTime);
      var num = db.SaveChanges();
   }
   transScope.Complete();
}
```

**Edit**: The proc deletes some rows based on the passed in datetime value and some other information known in the DB.

The proc definitely works - my integration tests verify that the table has the right number of rows following the execution of the proc - but I always get back 0 for the number of rows affected.

Ideas?

I'm running:  EF 4.3, MySQL 5.5.28, MySQL connector 6.5.4

---

**SOLVED:  See my answer below.**

Comment: what are you doing using your Stored procedure? I mean, what operation?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  But the proc takes in a date and performs some deletions based on that date and some other info in the db.

Comment: May be this helps. From documentation: If the last query was a DELETE query with no WHERE clause, all of the records will have been deleted from the table but this function will return zero with MySQL. When using UPDATE, MySQL will not update columns where the new value is the same as the old value. This creates the possibility that mysql_affected_rows() may not actually equal the number of rows matched, only the number of rows that were literally affected by the query.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  It IS a delete query with a WHERE clause, though.  It is only, in my test, deleting 1 row.  But it returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:**

Well, so the answer was to ignore the return of db.SaveChanges() and instead use the value that was being returned by the call to the procedure itself.  So, it looks like so now:

```
using (var transScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TimeSpan(0)))
{
   using (var db = new IceCreamEntities(connectionString, null, null))
   {
      var num = db.CallMyProc(dateTime);  //<<<<<< set it here instead
      db.SaveChanges();
   }
   transScope.Complete();
}
```

I had a bug in my tests that was making the db.CallMyProc call also return 0, so that was masking the fact that the call did return the number of rows affected.

Still not sure why SaveChanges doesn't but whatever.